# Is it possible to force the typescript compiler check all possible branches when having a return type?

Tags: typescript, tsconfig

I see that the typescript checker does not give a warning or an error when having a function like this:

```
function test(a: boolean): boolean {
    if (a) {
        return true;
    } else {
        // else branch not covered
    }
}
```

Is there a property that could be set in the tsconfig.json file to force the compiler to do the check? (I could not find any)

Comment: `noImplicitReturns` _should_ do about what you ask for, i think.

Comment: You will have to use a linter for that: https://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-empty

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The noImplicitReturns flag should do exactly that:

https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#noImplicitReturns

Comment: Or just use `strictNullChecks`, Typescript with throw because of undefined return on the function that is typed to return a boolean. Also, if you do `return false` after else block, neither `strictNullChecks` nor `noImplicitReturns` will warn about the empty else block.